# How to create an Client AngularJS SDK for own web services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, software-design

I already have API's built, I am trying to search for blog posts/articles that can help me gain more knowledge on how can one make an AngularJS SDK for exposing his web services.

I already know AngularJS, I have created a node js based web service for which I am trying create an SDK.

The problem that I am currently facing requires me to create an AngularJS SDK that my clients can integrate into their AngularJS websites so that they can consume my services.

Comment: do you mean you want to create API gateway using angular ? where users somehow inject your module and call the services?

Comment: My primary requirement includes writing some code, that AngularJS developers can use. I have been doing research on the same & so far I am able to deduce that an directive provided as NPM module should work

Comment: no not directive .. let me discuss with you on chat to tell you what you need to do and if sorted out all your stuff will post here as an answer

Comment: you need to have your module that contains your mainly services which they will call, directive if you want to create custom elements or attributes.

Comment: @HanyHabib you can connect with me on aktd95@gmail.com for further discussion